# Apply an application-level style to all textboxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

How do I apply a style defined in my Application.xaml to all the textboxes in a particular window? I don't want to type `Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"` with each and every of them because there are literally dozens of them. This is WPF + VS2010.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Then just add the `Style` to your `App.Xaml` or your `Theme.xaml` (if you have one) or even your `Window.Resources` if you just have 1 `Window`, just make sure you don't set the `x:Key`

Example:

This will apply to all `TextBoxes`(no x:Key)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

TextBoxes will have to use `Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"` to use this :

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It is one of those simple things that you wish you hadn't asked. Thanks a bunch.