# Visual Studio - WPF - Set standard Textstyle at designtime

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, fonts

how is it possible to set the standard textstyle (fontsize, fontfamily, etc), so every Control (Label, Textbox, etc) will display it's contents text with the new font right at designtime?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908148/apply-an-application-level-style-to-all-textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [TextElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement(v=vs.110).aspx) attached properties of your window directly in your XAML, something like that:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        TextElement.FontFamily="Bradley Hand ITC"
        TextElement.FontSize="16">

    // your XAML is here    

</Window>
```

Then - in order to avoid that this kind of "default text style" is used for runtime too - you just need to add this code in the window's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dependencyPropertyDescriptor = 
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, GetType());

        dependencyPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(this, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue);

        dependencyPropertyDescriptor =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, GetType());

        dependencyPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(this, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue);
    }
}
```

So if your `Window` is not in design time, the code removes unuseful styles.