# How to apply App.XAML style to current window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to apply validation error template and defining style in App.XAML.

```
<Application x:Class="MY.UI.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BP.NES.UI"
            >
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFCB2E2E" BorderThickness="1" Background="#11FF0000" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="errorBorder"/>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                            <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Left" 
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=errorBorder}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.IsFocused, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Polygon  VerticalAlignment="Center" Points="0,4 4,0 4,8" Fill="#FFCB2E2E" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFCB2E2E"
                                      StrokeThickness="2" />
                                    <Border Background="#FFCB2E2E" CornerRadius="4" Padding="4">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                   Text="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now in My Main Window I have following code:

```
<Window x:Class="MY.UI.View.MainWindow"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MY.UI.View"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MY.UI.ViewModel"
        xmlns:rules="clr-namespace:MY.UI.Validations"
        >
         <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
          <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                             x:Name="CellphoneNumberTextBox"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Margin="10,0,0,10"
                             IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=PereferenceRadio,Path=IsChecked}"
                             Text="{Binding CurrentEnrolmentDetail.CellNumber,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
          </TextBox>
            </Grid>
</Window>
```

If I move style to Window.Resources, it just works fine ,but when I have this in App.XAML , does not work. Is  this due to difference in namespace?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908148/apply-an-application-level-style-to-all-textboxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a style key in App.Xaml and use the key in your Textbox.

***Example:***

**App.Xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
</Style>
```

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Styles.ExplicitStyleSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ExplicitStyleSample" Height="150" Width="300">

<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <TextBlock>Header 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">Header 2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Header 3</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Or Override using BasedOn functionality**
Try this if you don't have interest to create style key

**App.Xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
<!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

I have declared my base styles in a ResourceDictionary in App.xaml, if i override them in a specific window like this, it usually works.

Comment: If  I need to apply all text boxes , why do I need to have an key?

Comment: I have updated the Answer to create override style to set for all the TextBox in your project.

Comment: @Simsons let me know whether second method is working for you or not.

Comment: It gives the error, Exception: Cannot find resource named 'TabItemStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If all TextBox will remain similar thought application than use following in resource file.

```
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
     </Style>
```

Else create key in App.xaml and use in the TextBox's where required as shown below:

```
 <Style x:Key="TextboxBackgroundColor" TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"/>
 </Style>
 <TextBox x:Name="txtText" Style="{StaticResource TextboxBackgroundColor}" />
```

Comment: Exception: Cannot find resource named 'TabItemStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.