# Apply a style to all textbox in my WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having an issue while I want to apply a style (font size) to all my textbox, where ever they are.

I, of course found those links :
[Apply an application-level style to all textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908148/apply-an-application-level-style-to-all-textboxes)

[How to target all controls (WPF Styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131034/how-to-target-all-controls-wpf-styles)

But this doesn't work for me.

The first one is still better because you don't need to use a key, and going to all your textbox.

I already have, in my app.xml, style applying to all controls (applying a color), so I tried something like this (even if this won't really be enough for me, since those styles are not everywhere) :

```
<Style x:Key="Type1Data" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FEE9E6"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

And as I said, I tried    this too, but won't work.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
            </Style>
```

Any idea what is my probleme and how I can achieve what I want to?
All  the hings I can find make me come back to the same code, and didn't found one that works.

**edit : here is my current app.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="myApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox"><!-- tried adding those 3 lines too-->
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Type1Data" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Type2Data" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Type3Data" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

As I said, the current styles does not cover the whole app (I add the key that is needed, or nothing)

**edit :** and if I add directly (as a second setter) font size to the Type 1,2 or 3, the font size apply. So it seems, there is no oter styles that are applying besides the 3 in app.xml.

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
```

Sample of code who should get a different textbox size(one with already a style, one without), they are in grid:

```
<com:ViewControl x:Class="myApp.View.ViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"  
             xmlns:input="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.View"
             xmlns:com="clr-namespace:RAPINF.PLL.Common;assembly=myApp.Common"
             xmlns:entities="clr-namespace:myApp.Entities;assembly=myApp.Entities"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="700">

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Type1Data}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Data.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Data.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

**edit : adding the code of the popup I use sometimes and works**

```
<sf:RibbonWindow x:Class="namespace:myApp.Common.DetailViewWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:sf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf" 
                xmlns:self="clr-namespace:myApp.Common"
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                d:Height="300" d:Width="400" 
                WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
                >
</sf:RibbonWindow>
```

How my usercontrol is added to the dock :

```
public void AddView(UserControl View, string sTitle, DockState docState)
{
    int Width = 800;
    int Height = 400;

    DockingManager.SetHeader(View, sTitle);
    DocumentContainer.SetMDIBounds(View, new Rect(30, 30, Width, Height));
    DockingManager.SetState(View, docState);
    DockingManager.SetShowCloseMenuItem(View, true);
    DockingManager.SetDesiredWidthInDockedMode(View, Width);

    DockManager.Children.Add(View);
    ActivateView(View);
}
```

If I use the dock I do this before :

```
ApplicationContext.Current.AddView(View, DockState.Document);
```

ANd with a popup, almost the same :

```
    DetailViewWindow dlg = new DetailViewWindow(View);
    dlg.ShowDialog();
```

As, those two code are used with the same View (yes, exactly the same), then I guess the problem comes from the fact of adding the view in the dock, and not in a popup window.

**Does the dock manager forces me to use a key?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us your App.xaml?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Added : as there were not much more than what I show, I didn't add the whole thing. mm8 : I provided the app.xml, but besides, I show all what I tried, and the results is, nothing appened on the font size of my textbox.

Comment: Why are you expecting any of the Type1Data, Type2Data and Type3Data styles to all TextBoxes? You should add an implicit style (without an x:Key) with a TargetType of TextBox to your App.xaml.

Comment: @mm8 that is just some of the things I tried. By implicit you mean : <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        </Style> ? I already tried this ( edit code). If not, can you explain more? I am not used to those global styles.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Can you show the code/markup for the actual TextBox to which you expect the style to get applied?

Comment: Your issue is still not reproducible. Please upload a minimal sample project somewhere and post the link to it here if you need any further help.

Comment: @mm8 it will be hard to give you more complete code, but I did find something. When the Control is openned in the DockingManager, it won't work, but when it is opened in a popup (will add the code), and using a dlg.show on it, it works. But this is the same control, maybe the problem come from the DockManager?

Comment: Obviously. This is why you should always provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6):

I can't reproduce your problem. I can just show you a working example. Maybe it's helping you finding your problem.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Name="MyWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <TextBox Width="150"/>
</Window>
```

**Output**

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes, that is a code I found (see links on my question) . And it is exactly my problem : what should works, sadly doesn't.

Comment: Like mm8 said. You have to provide a minimal sample where we can reproduce the problem. Otherwise it's almost impossible. Maybe there is somewhere else a Style which overrides the one in the App.xaml.

Comment: added a precision : if I add directly to the Type 1,2 or 3, the font size apply (second setter in the style), it works, so there is nothing besides Type1,2 or 3 that seems to be applying. And since it doesn't use Fontsize... But as those 3 styles are not everywhere, I need something else.

Comment: I understand what you are meaning but something has to interfere. Otherwise it would work. That's why it's a good start to seperate the problem. Depends on the size of your project. Sometimes it helps deleting everything else (step by step) to check what's making trouble. When using an version control system you can just revert after finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too had no problem with the styling.  But I typically break my stuff into separate dictionaries for different controls and derive from some of my own classes.  I also define a style and assign a "x:Key" name to it.  This is like saying I have a class with this key name and I want it to look like this.  Then, once I get it working, I take the final class and say use your style based on the key defined...  Having said that, Here is a stripped basic of the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="STextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="WingDings" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource STextBox}" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I can define all sorts of things about my base-style "STextBox" (via the x:Key).  But after, I set the style with a target BASED ON the style via x:Key.  The critical thing I think you were missing is the target must be of {x:Type TextBox}.

If you look at the xmlns headers at the top such as

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

the "x=" is the alias of the library it is getting control types.  By you generically declaring the

```
TargetType="TextBox"
```

You are not specifically associating to the CLASS TYPE.

Then in my main window (and anywhere else in the app), I have this in my main grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Testing" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="Another Line" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Last" />

</Grid>
```

and they all work properly.  You can also change default colors, size, font family, margins, etc to the base style and all will change without explicit reference to every control.